# MSAL + OAUTH token refresh

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

I may be answering my own question here but would like some assurance.

For a Azure event hub producer client (.net) using OAUTH token authN will token refresh be performed within the MSAL Classes OR would it be connection/message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAL handles token refresh.
When you ask for a token silently, MSAL will first check if it has a token in cache that is still valid.
If yes, it'll return that.
If not, it checks if there is a refresh token in cache.
It'll then try to use that to get new tokens, cache them, and return them.
If the refresh fails, you will get an exception.

Comment: That is what I thought, so the token wouldn't be per transaction/message level?

Comment: No. The AAD tokens contain no info about a transaction or message. They only say that this is a token for this principal (user or app), and it is meant for the Service Bus API. Service Bus uses the info in the token to then figure out if the call is authorized.